# mysql, specific charachter not saved correctly in the database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a java application,
In my jsp page I have:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
...
function addToDB(){
      jQuery.post(document.myForm.action=getContextPath()+'/myAction.do?method=create' , 
             jQuery("form[name='myForm']").serialize(), function(data) {
               jQuery("#myDiv").show();
             });   
}
```

...

```
<nested:text property="productName" />
<nested:text property="productOwner" />
...
```

when I enter :

product Name : my Product

product Owner : Mäy

In the database I get : MÃ¶y instead of Mäy

Why it isn't saved correctly?

Comment: what is the charset of your database?

Comment: character_set_database utf8

Comment: Can you check if  the collation for the columns, tables and the database are all set to utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_general_ci?

Comment: And try mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); when selecting data from your db, this keeps data going in and out of your db in UTF8 format

Comment: collation_connection utf8_general_ci, 
collation_database utf8_unicode_ci,
collation_server utf8_general_ci

Comment: Try set mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

Comment: You encode in a different format than you decode. Try this in Python: `print u"ä".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could/should add

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
```

to the post method.

Hope this helps!

Regards
Patrick